# What is the difference between web3 and window.web3

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapp-development, javascript

I'm very used to using `web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)` and I saw [here](https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8) that MetaMask sample code is using `window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)`

What's the difference between using and not using the `window` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function

If web3 is not defined as a global variable, but you have "web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)" inside a function - the web3 object will be local for that function only, while with window.web3 it will be globaly accessible